# Jquery slider with left right top and bottom

Tags: jquery

Hi all I would like to add top and bottom to this existing script, I tried to modify the javascript as required but I am not able to see the top and bottom arrows. I added the following img tag

```
<div class="next-anchor">
    <img src="~/images/large_down.png">
</div>
```

```js
if (index === 0) {
    $('.horizon-prev').hide();
    $('.horizon-next').show();
    $('.next-anchor').show();
} else if (index === $.fn.horizon.defaults.limit - 1) {
    $('.horizon-prev').show();
    $('.horizon-next').hide();
    $('.next-anchor').show();
} else {
    $('.horizon-next').show();
    $('.horizon-prev').show();
    $('.next-anchor').show();
}
```

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Horizontal-Scrolling-Website-with-jQuery-horizonScroll-js/

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? It's really not clear at the moment

Comment: I would like to merge this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Vertical-Horizontal-Page-Scrolling-Plugin-with-jQuery-ALXS-Slidestack/ with in that existing plugin

Comment: Did you add references to slidestack.js and slidestack.settings.js in your code?

Comment: Could you post more of your code?